# Automatically send "Email verification" email after successful register in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to Automatically send "Email verification" email after a successful register in Laravel 8.5

My `RegisterController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
            'password' =>['required', 'min:6', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have this two routes which work, but I have to do it manualy:

```
Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'sendVerificationEmail'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

In Laravel docs I found that I should add `event(new Registered($User));` in my register controller but variable $user is not defined. What should I pass as variable?

Answer (score 1):

The variable you shall pass must be a User object, that means that you either have to fetch it from the database after creation or save the new user in a variable, have a look at the code below :)

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
            'password' =>['required', 'min:6', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        $user = new User(); 
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();

        event(new Registered($user));
    }
}
```

Hopefully the code above will give you the result you are looking for. Otherwise, fetch the new user from the database and pass it to the **Registered** event such as this:

```
event(new Registered(User::where('email', $request->email)->first()));
```

Good luck! :)